# Fs is read only, "mount -n -o remount /" not working since the fs is not writeable

Tags: mount, filesystem, fstab, read-only

How can I remount my filesystem rw if the filesystem is read only?

Comment: Still need help with this issue please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file system might be corrupted. Boot your computer using LiveCD/DVD or LiveUSB, and try to repair the disk using `fsck`.

After the execution has completed, reboot and check if everything's all right.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following command :

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Comment: I got the message "cannot remount block device /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected"